# NGINX Allow CORS for location and all sub folders

Tags: nginx, cors

I am trying to permit CORS for a cdn site but am struggling with the correct regex -
I want to allow CORS for a specific location and all subfolders within that location :

```
location /cdn/lib/ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_pass http://cdn_server_1;
}
```

This is only working for `/cdn/lib` and not `/cdn/lib/sub1/sub2/sub3`

What is the correct syntax to allow CORS for all subfolders and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regex method in folder path to solve this problem. For example:

```
location ~ ^/cdn/(.*)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_pass http://cdn_server_1;
}
```

This will make possible set headers for all cdn folders